# Having trouble with simple probability question

Tags: probability

> $\mathsf{2010. 3F.}$ $N$ horses take part in $m$ races. The results of
>   different races are independent. The probability for horse $i$ to win
>   any given race is $p_i\geq 0,$ with $p_1+\dots+p_N =1$. Let $Q$ be the
>   probability that a single horse wins all $m$ races. Express $Q$ as a
>   polynomial of degree m in the variables $p_1, \dots, p_N $.

This question should be straightforward but I think I am misunderstanding something. Shouldn't:

$$Q=\sum_i\mathbb{P}(i\;\text{wins all races})\prod_{j\neq i}\mathbb{P}(j\;\text{does not win all races})=\sum_{i=1}^N p_i^m\prod_{j\neq i}(1-p_j^m)?$$

$Q$ is not even close to being a polynomial of degree $m$, it is of degree $Nm$. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Think about this: What is the probability that a horse wins a race? It's just $p_i$, not $p_i\prod_{j\neq i}(1-p_j)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that a horse wins a race is just $p_i$; it is *not* $p_i\prod_{j\neq i}(1-p_j)$.

So : $\mathbb{P}(\text{horse }i\text{ wins all }m\text{ races})=p_i^m$

Hence, for all horses:
$$\mathbb{Q} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i^m$$

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one winner by race, isn't it ? So, $Q=\sum \mathbb{P}(i \text{wins all races}) =\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^m$.

The problem in your explanation, is that you shall have written "j does not win all races knowing that i wins all races and this probability is one if $i\neq j$

Comment: Of course, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to a misinterpretation of the given information. The question clearly implies that when one horse wins a race, none of the other horses wins, which is why the sum of the winning probabilities is 1. Your answer would be correct if say winning the race just amounts to completing it, in which case it is possible for more than one horse or even no horse to win each race. Wait, that's not a race is it?

Comment: Yes, I was being daft. Thanks!